mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable uses the init property?
Note: I'm new to C# so I might have misunderstood something about object initializers.
Consider this Minimal Reproducible Example (complete code at the end)

We define an IDataView object from an IEnumerable.
We want to put it back into another IEnumerable but that contains another (though with the same column names) object.
This second class has 2 properties that are arrays. If the property is only 'get', it won't be updated/initialized by mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable (they'll be initialized to 0 and never updated). Otherwise, it will be updated/initialized by mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable.

I thought that because the property is an array, it doesn't matter that it is get only because I can get it (get the reference to that object), and then modify its elements freely.
However, it appears mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable wants to replace that array with another one. Weirdly enough, if it is get only, I don't even get an Error. So I'm a bit confused.
Reading the complete MRE might yield a clearer view of what I don't understand:
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var mlContext = new MLContext();

        SampleInput a = new SampleInput() { Value1 = new float[] { 1.0f }, Value2 = new float[] { 1.0f } };
        SampleInput b = new SampleInput() { Value1 = new float[] { 2.0f }, Value2 = new float[] { 2.0f } };
        List<SampleInput> inputData = [a, b];

        // Convert input data to IDataView
        IDataView inputView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData);
        // Use CreateEnumerable to convert back to a list of SampleOutput
        var outputData = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<SampleOutput>(inputView, reuseRowObject: false);
        // Print the output
        foreach (var output in outputData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Field1: {string.Join(", ", output.Field1)}");  // 1 and 2, I'm happy about that
            Console.WriteLine($"Field2: {string.Join(", ", output.Field2)}");  // Always 0????????? 
            // But didn't throw an error when it tried to initialize the array????
        }
    }
}

public class SampleInput
{
    [ColumnName("Value1")]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Value1 { get; set; }

    [ColumnName("Value2")]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Value2 { get; set; }
}


public class SampleOutput
{
    [ColumnName("Value1")]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Field1 { get; init; } = new float[1];

    [ColumnName("Value2")]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Field2 { get; } = new float[1];
}

Note:
Rider itself says "Auto-property can be made get-only" which (obviously) is not true given the example.
It is fairly logical that mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable uses the init property, but why does it not throw any errors when I don't allow init?
It clearly should (this works, this throws an error but Field2 doesn't throw an error when mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable fails to update it).
I tried looking at the source code but got lost.

you haven't showed us all the code(no mre). Also what is the question?

@IvanPetrov I'm not sure I understand, there is a MRE in my post (and it was included from the start)

A common scenario of mapping is to create an object of the target type, and then invoke setters of this new object. As I understood from source code, it uses naming convention to match properties of the old type and property of the new type.
Code looks perfectly fine, you did not declare a possibility to set a value and a method did not set it, because neither init or set were accessible. Why did not you add it? (rhetorical question). Maybe you don't care about specific columns and you "ignore" them by omitting specific properties. It would be not wise from authors to always throw exception.
As for the array field assignment, yes, you can modify elements of the array even if init was used, because it is used only for assignment operator of the given property, not for the properties/indices of its type.
About Rider suggestion - Rider (and other IDEs like Visual Studio) uses reflection to understand how types are being used. There is no usage of setter in your code, but it does not necessarily mean that it won't be attempted to be used. IDE simply can't know how types are used through reflection, especially by 3rd party dependencies. What you can do is supress the warning by picking it from quick actions, just for this property, or for the whole class or file.
So, considering all this knowledge, your output class should look like this. You might want to change set to init, but it does not matter in this scenario
public class SampleOutput
{
    [ColumnName("Value1")]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Field1 { get; set; }

    [ColumnName("Value2")]
    [VectorType(1)]
    public float[] Field2 { get; set; }
}

Take a look at the Convert method below - CreateEnumerable method might look somewhat like this under the hood. Notice how many warnings Rider generate.
using System.Reflection;

var input = new SampleInput()
{
    Field1 = [3f, 4f],
    Field2 = [5f, 6f]
};

var output = Convert<SampleInput, SampleOutput>(input);

Console.WriteLine($"Output Field1.Length: {output.Field1.Length}, Field2.Length: {output.Field2.Length}");

K Convert<T, K>(T tObj)
{
    var tProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); // get properties of source type
    var kProperties = typeof(K).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); // get properties of target type

    var kObj = (K)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(K)); // create object of target type

    foreach (var tProperty in tProperties) // iterate over properties of the target type
    {
        var kProperty = kProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == tProperty.Name); // match property by name (or other convention)
        if (kProperty != null && kProperty.CanWrite) // make sure there is init; or set; present on the property
        {
            var value = tProperty.GetValue(tObj); // get value of the source object
            
            kProperty.SetValue(kObj, value); // write value to the target object
        }
    }
    
    return kObj;
}

public class SampleInput
{
    public float[] Field1 { get; set; } = []; //warning: get is never used
    public float[] Field2 { get; set; } = []; //warning: get is never used
}

public class SampleOutput
{
    public float[] Field1 { get; init; } = []; //warning: init is never used
    public float[] Field2 { get; } = [];
}

Output: Output Field1.Length: 2, Field2.Length: 0
You can obviously flip if (kProperty != null && kProperty.CanWrite) condition to throw an exception if property is missing on the target type

Thanks for the answer! I understand I should have my output class as you shown but I'm not sure I understand why only having gets does not raise an error. You say "a method did not set it, because neither init or set were accessible" but shouldn't it raise an error if those are not accessible? Like this (https://dotnetfiddle.net/5oD3O7)?

The error you show is a compile time error - compiler analyzes code, sees that you don't have setter, but you try to assign to a property - boom, error. You can't get this error in runtime - when app is running, code from library checks what properties it can write to. It chooses to skip property, if setter is not present. It is custom logic in library, not some kind of enforcement by compiler

Ah I see, so here the compiler doesn't have the capacity to see that mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable wants to use an init property and therefore doesn't throw an error and at runtime when it tries it doesn't see the init property and chooses to skip instead of throwing a runtime error?

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows please check update

The issue lies in some misunderstanding of the properties get; set; and innit; on your class attributes.
get; allows you to READ the attribute from outside the class.  eg in your code you can read SampleOut1.Field1[]
if you have ONLY the get; property in your class definition for the attribute you will only be able to read the Field1[] array in this manner.
set; will allow you to also set the value of SampleOut1.Field1[] = someArray[]
if you do not allow set, you then would need to write a public function that could then manipulate the Field1[] attribute.
innit; is all-together different.  It allows editting of Field1[] ONLY at object initialization.  After that, you cannot modify the attribute outside of the class.  You initialize it to new float[1] in your class definition.  It works the same as just having public float Field1[] {get;} = new float[1]
My assumption here is that you probably do not want to use this property, it will prevent you doing the task you outlined earlier in the question.  You will not be able to replace Field1 in your SampleOutput object with SampleOutput.Field1 = diffArrayOfData
For clarity, "outside the class" means through the class attribute accessor SampleOutput.Field1
In order to modify this array, or its elements, you will need a public method in your class.  eg SampleOutput.ReplaceField1(someFloatArray)

But if you get an array, you can modify the elements of that array, correct? I didn't understand the end of your message, my MRE shows that the property has to be init to work? Sorry if I misunderstood something.

If you use the get property and not the set property, you cannot modify the array, or its elements, from outside the class.  You cannot use the syntax SampleOutput1.FieldArray1 = someOtherArray in your main class.  The innit property allows you to set the attribute one time, at object initialization, and then the get, but no set, makes it read only after that.  You initialize the object to new float[1], meaning you cannot modify it again from outside the class.

Yes but you can do SampleOutput1.FieldArray1[1] = 2 right?

And also, which was the main question I had, how come the mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable function in my example uses init? and when I don't allow init it doesn't throw an error

No, you cannot use the accessor in that manner to set the value if you do not use the set; property.  The reason it throws an error with the innit; property is because you initialize the array in the SampleOutput class when you define the Field1 attribute, and then try to set it with your line .  var outputData = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable(inputView, reuseRowObject: false);  The innit property only lets you set it one time, via object innitializer, which you're using when you define the attribute with = new float[1];  or in the object constructor, which you don't have.

I'm saying precisely it doesn't throw an error when i don't use init which is what I'm curious about

This proves you can change an array property that only has a get: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ndAQ5

This is an interesting behavior with assigning array element values and not reassigning the whole array object.  This line produces the expected error:  obj.MyArray = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };  in your sample you linked.  Note, in your application up top, the line var outputData = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable(inputView, reuseRowObject: false);  is attempting to reassign the entire array object, which is previously defined here: public float[] Field1 { get; init; } = new float[1]; and the innit property doesn't allow that reassignment.  If you use only get property, this is allowed

because that reassignment is being done during object construction

Yes exactly! So my question is why does mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable use reassignment during object construction and does NOT throw an error when I don't allow init. It SHOULD throw an error but it DOES NOT. And I'm super confused.

It only throws an error when you use the innit; property because that's how the innit; property works.  The get; property prevents reassignment OUTSIDE of the class.  Technically, you're reassigning within the class during construction, so using only the get; property does not throw an error.

Well I'm obviously using the init, otherwise both field would be initialized and my MRE shows only the one with init gets initialized.

You are initializing them both by definition.  you are setting them = new float[1];  You are getting the error from the innit; property on Field1.  You are getting it because you initialize it by definition, and then you try to reassign it with this line: var outputData = mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable(inputView, reuseRowObject: false);  Your error is because the innit; property restricts assignment to only happening once.

I don't understand, what error are you talking about? Did you run my code? There are no errors in my code. The code runs and prints without problems. Which is precisely my problem.

Field2 will work fine with only a get accessor because you manually initialise it in it's declaration so init is not needed. The init keyword allows a property to be set just once during its construction, but you set the value during its definition.
Field2 does not need a set because you are not changing the value of Field2 in your code anywhere. The set keyword would be needed to reassign Field2 with another array value but can get the array already stored in Field2 and update its contents without set.
The reason mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable is not causing any compile time errors is because it is a generic method that has no knowledge of the details of the type that you provide it until runtime, so no error can be produced before runtime. The reason there are no runtime errors will be due to some handling of access/operation limitations to properties within the provided type within mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable.

But if "Field2 does not need a set because you are not changing the value of Field2 but it's contents." the contents of Field2 would be changed right? They are not changed as printed in my MRE.

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Apologies, I missed that. I've updated my answer.
